# My program prevents Windows from shutting down!

Tags: c, windows, winapi, wxwidgets

My wxwidgets program does not allow the computer to shutdown when the user clicks on Shutdown. I had issues with exiting the program normally so I've been calling exit() directly instead of deleting the top window as wxwidgets says to do. The exit workaround has been working but it seems wxwidgets can't exit when it receives shutdown window signal (?). Can I trap this somehow and just call exit so that the program does not block windows from shutting down?

Answer (score 2):

Windows sends the `WM_SHUTDOWN` message to all applications. This event is mapped to `EVT_END_SESSION` in your wxWidgets application. Make sure you handle this event appropriately.

See the [wxCloseEvent Class Reference](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_close_event.html).

In case of problems also try handling `EVT_QUERY_END_SESSION`, which is related to `WM_QUERY_END_SESSION`. This message is send before `WM_SHUTDOWN` to give applications the possibility to cancel the shutdown.

Comment: I have EVT_END_SESSION(HandleEndSessionEvent) in my MainApp object which is derived from wxApp. void MainApp::HandleEndSessionEvent(wxCloseEvent& event). It never gets called. Does this look right?

Answer (score 1):

When Windows is shutting down it posts WM_SHUTDOWN message to all applications that have window

Are you able to catch that message?